# Determining whether selected image originated from device camera

Tags: android

Images on the Android device can originate from many different sources - from the device camera, from an external SD card, from an e-mail, synced from another system.  I'm developing an application which uploads images from an Android device to a web application.  It turns out that the web application can perform some significant optimizations if it can be determined that the uploaded image originated from the device's camera.

I guess that this would have to be done at the point that the Android application user selects the image from those presented in the picker.  At that point, the Android application has an image in hand.  Is there image metadata available, and, if so, would it include a marker which indicates that the image originates from the device's camera?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Peter Hornby

Answer (score 1):

Peter,

If you view the EXIF data for the JPEG you should be able to see the camera type it was taken with.  On my droid it says "Motorola Droid" for the camere type.

Here is a link to an android class for reading EXIF data: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/12/read-exif-information-in-jpeg-file.html

Comment: Willy, thanks - that looks like what I need.  I'll get to work.